# windows 10 make progress failed

Tags: linux, windows-10, make

I have installed a package from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow and I am trying to build a target using make, so I run this command :

```
make -f tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/Makefile test_hello_world_test
```

But it failed and here is the error message:

```
-m was unexpected at this time.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/Makefile:585: *** Something went wrong with the flatbuffers download: The top-level downloads directory: tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads does not exist..  Stop.
```

Here is some lines near line 585 in the Makefile:

```
 # Directly download the flatbuffers library.
  DOWNLOAD_RESULT := $(shell $(MAKEFILE_DIR)/flatbuffers_download.sh ${MAKEFILE_DIR}/downloads)
  ifneq ($(DOWNLOAD_RESULT), SUCCESS)
    $(error Something went wrong with the flatbuffers download: $(DOWNLOAD_RESULT))
  endif
```

Could you please explain where is wrong and how can I fix it? Thank you.